# How to group by column for data spread across numerous json files

Tags: java, json

Currently, I have a large database that logs some metric of accounts on the server every minute. Each minutely log is saved as an individual json file. For demonstration, one json file recorded from 12:00 AM to 12:01 AM would look like this:

```
{
    "accountId": "1010101",
    "time": "2021-06-05T00:00:00.000Z",
    "Metric": 15
}
    ...

{
    "accountId": "999999",
    "time": "2021-06-05T00:00:00.000Z",
    "metric": 3
}
```

However, for my purposes I need to group by accountId over days worth of data. That is, I need to create a json file for each accountId, in which it shows the account metric over a certain amount of days. For instance if there are 1000 accounts on the server which I need to look at 3 days worth of data for, I would create 1000 json files that would look like this:

```
{
    accountId: "101010",
    array: [
        {
            "time": "2021-06-05T00:00:00Z"
            "metric": 15
        }

        ...

        {
            "time": "2021-06-07T23:59:00Z"
            "metric": 20
        }
    ]
}
```

Because this is a minutely recorded data on a large server, the number of json files as well as the size of the files are quite large when looking at days worth of data. Is there a particular strategy and recommended library to use when attempting to parse json files in this manner?

Comment: The best strategy to have a single instance of each event in a log file, and to only generate what is needed as required. Are you really sure you want to create log files with duplicate information? Is another application using these log files in some way? Can't they be generated from a database on the fly if another service relies on the JSON files?

Comment: I'd recommend a database to log into. Alternatively read the log files and write into a database. Then extract the info. 
If you want to do it "by hand": Go trough your log files. For each new id you find, create a new file and initialize it with a "header" JSON. For each id append the current JSON part to the id file. Afterwards go over your id files and finalize the JSON structure with a "footer".